# Sell app including AndroidPlot

Tags: android, open-source, publishing, androidplot

Now that androidplot's website i down, i'd hear if any of you know whether it is legal to sell an application using AndroidPlot? Should i place their name somewhere?
Cheers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://androidplot.com/wiki/License:

Copyright 2010 AndroidPlot.com. All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in binary form, without modification, is
permitted provided that the following condition is met:

```
  Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
  of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
  provided with the distribution.
```

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY ANDROIDPLOT.COM ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL ANDROIDPLOT.COM OR
CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON
ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF
ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation are those of the
authors and should not be interpreted as representing official policies, either expressed
or implied, of AndroidPlot.com.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update on this one - AndroidPlot has switched to the Apache 2.0 license in the hope that it will be less restrictive and easier to understand:

http://androidplot.com/about/#License